# PreparedStatement SetDate reduces date value by 1

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I came across this strange issue when working with PreparedStatement and I cannot seem to figure out the exact reason behind this. 
I use the setDate function to set the date to the PreparedStatement as follows:

```
query = "UPDATE gantt_tasks SET date_column = ? WHERE id = 1";
connection = new MySqlConnection().getConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2013-09-04"));
```

which is pretty straightforward. However, after the date is set, when I check on the `preparedStmt` object, the Date value is set to it as `"2013-09-03"` rather than the actual date value I set, which was `"2013-09-04"`. What am I doing wrong here?

I also noticed that a similar issue happens when using the setTime() function as well. There, it reduces the time by 30 mins, i.e. when I pass `"08:00:00"` it sets the value as `"07:30:00"`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the default timezone of the JVM, which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using, what is the (default) session timezone of MySQL?

Comment: default timezone of the JVM is set as Asia/Colombo (UTC +5.30), MySql connector version is 8.0.13 and my mysql database is hosted on AWS, whch I assume is on UTC by default.

Comment: Use Java [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) api.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for steering me in the right direction! :) seems like it was indeed an issue with the timezone difference between the JVM and the mysql instance. I changed the AWS timezone to my current timezone and the issue is fixed now. thanks again!

Comment: Also, as Sedrick hinted, consider using `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

Comment: I run into the same problem. Using of `java.time.LocalDate` doesn't help in this case. `statement.setObject(position, LocalDate.of(2013, 9, 4));` still sets DATE in the table to `2013-09-03`. It is obviously related to timezone, but my mysql server is running on localhost, with system timezone, which is equal to JVM, so, it's strange.